# Как правильно загружать спрайты из массива в canvas HTML5

Tags: javascript, массивы, html5, canvas

Есть такой массив, и нужно по путям изображений предварительно их загрузить, что-бы это делать не налету.

```
var array_srpite = [
     './sprite/sprite1.png',
     './sprite/sprite2.png',
     './sprite/sprite3.png',
     './sprite/sprite4.png',
     './sprite/sprite5.png',
     './sprite/sprite6.png',
}
```

Сейчас я их загружаю на ходу, локально то всё окей работает, а вот на сервере начинает тупить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var array_srpite_images = array_srpite.map(item => {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = item;
  return img;
});
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое во второй раз...

Comment: @HRLDeveloper На здоровье. Успехов!